# What is Sword Level?

Tags: candy-box

What is Sword Level?

I know that the effects of the Swords of Life and Flames are affected by it, but how do I know what level my sword is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sword level by going to your inventory. It is shown just below the sword
[image: Sword Level Circled in Red]